# Can not change state while trying to update value

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react  and i am creating an employee form where i have to send gender info into JSON format. 
initialstate

```
constructor(){

    super()
    this.state ={
        gender:{
            gender:""
        },
 }
```

Here i defined my initial state .
handleChange event part

```
handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
    type === "checkbox" ? this.setState({ [name]: checked }) : this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```

i am handling checkbox type data here  to update value of current state.
here is the handle submit part. I have to send data to an API in this format

```
gender: {
gender:"male"
}
handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

        const obj = this.state

        console.log(this.obj)
        axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',this.state)

  }
```

form part

```
 <div className="form-group">
       <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
            <div className="radio" style={genderRadio}>
                   <label>
                     <input type="radio" value="male" checked={this.state.gender.gender === "male"} onChange={this.handleChange} name="gender"  />Male</label>

              </div>
             <div className="radio">
                   <label>
                      <input type="radio"  value="female" checked={this.state.gender.gender === "female"} onChange={this.handleChange} name="gender"/>Female</label>
             </div>
             <div className="radio ">
                <label>
                   <input type="radio"  value="others" checked={this.state.gender.gender === "others"} onChange={this.handleChange} name="gender" />Others</label>
             </div> 


  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide working example, like on jsfiddle, codepen? I'm having trouble understanding what is the issue there and what's not working for you

Comment: if i initialize this.state ={ gender: " " } , then changing input it changes state . But i have to initialize state like this this.state ={gender : {gender:" "}} . then the state is not changing. thank you

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you are using a gender value inside a gender object inside state ?

Comment: yes , because i have to send data  in this format to an api .

Comment: Why don't you keep the state part clean without objects and finally build the object structure you require in the handle submit function. Your code will be much neater that way.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onChange` handler as follows

```
      handleChange(event) {
            const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
            if(type === "checkbox"){
              this.setState({ [name]: checked })
            } else {
              if(name=== "gender"){
                this.setState({ gender: { gender: value });
              } else {
                this.setState({ [name]: value })
              }
            }
        }
```

The issue arises because you are nesting gender inside another gender object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to bind the `this` keyword inside your `handleChange` function so that it points to the component's execution context.

Either explicitly bind it in your constructor, or use an arrow-function. If you don't then, the `this` keyword will be `undefined` and therefore you cannot use `this.setState()`

Additionally, you have a a `gender` object with its own field called `gender` in your component-state. There are two levels of data you need to account for. So updating the inner-gender value will not be as simple as doing this `this.setState({ [name]: checked })`

See working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-maxwell-piobv

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      gender: {
        gender: ""
      }
    };
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    if (type !== "checkbox") {
      this.setState(
        {
          [name]: {
            ...this.state[name],
            [name]: value
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const obj = this.state;

    console.log(this.obj);
    // axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", this.state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="male"
              checked={this.state.gender.gender === "male"}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="gender"
            />
            Male
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="female"
              checked={this.state.gender.gender === "female"}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="gender"
            />
            Female
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio ">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="others"
              checked={this.state.gender.gender === "others"}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="gender"
            />
            Others
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with updating the state. Try the following alternative.

```
** Current:**

handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
    type === "checkbox" ? this.setState({ [name]: checked }) : this.setState({ 
   [name]: value })
}

**Solution:**

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={
        data:{
            gender:""
        },
 }

handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
    this.setState({
         data:{
           [name]: type =="checkbox" ? checked : value
         }
    })

}
```